# sending an array using a form and sessions (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have looked at this post [PHP, pass array through POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071587/php-pass-array-through-post)
but cannot quite get it working.

I have a form as below:

```
<applications><h2>Applications</h2><br><input type="checkbox" name="apps[]" value="gg">gg<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="apps[]" value="aa">aa<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="apps[]" value="bb">bb<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="apps[]" value="cc">cc<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="apps[]" value="dd">dd<br><br>
    </applications>

<servers>
<h2>Servers</h2><br><input type="checkbox" name="serv[]" value="servera">servera<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="serv[]" value="serverb">serverb<br><br>

</servers>
<countries1><h2>Countries</h2><br><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="uk">UK<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="germany">Germany<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="france">France<br><br>

</countries1>
<countries2>
<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="spain">Spain<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="sweeden">Sweeden<br><br>
</countries2>

<submitb>
<?
session_start();

$_SESSION['country']=$country;
$_SESSION['serv']=$serv;
$_SESSION['apps']=$apps;?>
<input type="submit" value="Update">

</submitb>

</form>
```

Then on my retrieval end:

```
 $apps=$_SESSION['apps'];

     $countries=$_SESSION['country'];
     $servers= $_SESSION['serv'];
```

EDIT:Please could someone advise me what I am doing wrong here? I am receiving:
Undefined index: apps in C:\wamp\www\notifcation system\done.php on line 41

Comment: You are missing a semi colon here: $apps=$_SESSION['apps'];

Comment: Thank you! updated with new issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
  $apps=$_SESSION['apps']; /* fix missing semicolon */
  $countries=$_SESSION['country'];
  $servers= $_SESSION['serv'];
?>
```

For your other issue:

```
Undefined index: apps in ...
```

Simply means that `$apps` is not defined. This is not an error, but a notice.

Try this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['apps'])){
   $apps=$_SESSION['apps'];
} // etc
```

Comment: Can't believe it was so simple. As a PHP beginner I always assume I must be doing it wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can't yet or would of. Having a new issue though related, so would appreciate guidance on that too.

Comment: I have updated my answer. PS your questions are VERY basic and you should find an answer by doing a little searching around. Also do not update your posts when  you have new questions; create a new topic instead.

Comment: I am aware they are basic, and did look around but couldn't find my specific issue. Thanks none the less.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `session_start();` should always be on the first line of the page, then you will start adding things later.

Also the `session_start();` should be on every page you need acces to your session to.

as mentioned above by @subzero, never forget the all important `;` semicolons as in PHP, these things can break your code.