# How do you make an array stay set on reload?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a signup form and an array called $errors. When the user submits the form, it checks for errors and adds them to the $errors array. Everything works just fine, except for one thing; when the page loads after being submitted, the array is empty. How can I make this array stay put?

Thanks!

Comment: If the page is reloaded - it's another page. Why to keep old errors?

Comment: @zerkms If the username is already in the database, I want it to tell the user. When you click submit, it's basically reloading the page. The entire system works, but I just can't get the array to carry over when the user submits it. (Edited the question to make that more clear)

Comment: Please show us your code so far so we can have a look.

Comment: @Dubstaphone: if user clicked submit - you have the data posted so can revalidate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post the errors array and then repopulate it from the $_POST data. Alternatively you could write the errors array to a file and then read them in from that file each time + the new errors.

There are probably a couple of other ways but those're the first two I thought of.

Comment: Okay, I'll try the first and see where that goes. Should I serialize it first? Thanks!

Comment: I find a post that might be helpful about posting arrays.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071587/php-pass-array-through-post