# PHP array failing to POST with other form data

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, hidden

I have an array named $content_ids which I am trying to post as a hidden field in a form.

I found out how to do this from another answer here but I cant get it to work.

Here are just a few of my inputs including the hidden field for the array

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\" name=\"e\">";
foreach($content_ids as $ids)
{
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$ids."\" name=\"ids[]\">";
}
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$content[$x]['TranslationID']."\" name=\"translationID\">";
```

Trying to print_r($_POST['ids']) shows nothing

Trying this:

```
if($_POST['ids'] != ""){
    echo "hello";
}
```

also gives nothing. But the rest of the data is passing through ok.

Anybody any idea why?

Edit to add:  Tested to make sure the array actually contains the data at the point of placing it into the hidden field. printing out the array immediately before the hidden field is set and all displays ok.

Edit to add: how the array is made:

```
$content_ids = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++)
    {
        $content_ids[] = array_push($content_ids, $content[$i]['ContentID']);   
    }
```

the output for the array is:

Array ( [0] => 2222 [1] => 1 [2] => 1111 [3] => 3 )

I actually dont know why index 1 or index 3 are there. They are not part of the data from the database. It should only contain 1111 and 2222.

Comment: have you tried `if(!empty)` instead of `!= ""`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071587/php-pass-array-through-post

Comment: use ´var_dump($_POST[]);´ to check the post and see if it has the data in there at all.

Comment: Using var_dump shows all values except the array I need

Comment: Can you show the values of array `$content_ids`?

Comment: Ok, can you please post the resulting html that makes up the form?. Maybe these hidden inputs aren't really being output (maybe $content_ids is not an array???).

Comment: If $ids is an array, you cannont put it in a string, if it is not, you should name this variable $id.

Comment: @The Marlboro Man Before I post my html I am interested in what you said about my array maybe not being an array. As the array is being populated from a database I am just looking at it to see that I have done it correctly. $content_ids is populated with the data I need. But you could be right with it not being a propper array

Comment: As I can see in your code trough the latest edit, you seem to be creating an array of arrays, instead of a single-dimension array. Iterating through each value would equal to stringifyng an array, which is not what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I believe the issue was with the creation of the array.

The only thing I changed was:

```
$content_ids = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++)
    {
        $content_ids[] = array_push($content_ids, $content[$i]['ContentID']);   
    }
```

And I changed it to this:

```
$content_ids = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++)
    {
        array_push($content_ids, $content[$i]['ContentID']);    
    }
```

I dont know how but this seems to have fixed both the unwanted indexes in the array and the failure to post as a hidden field.

I am now getting the array successfully as a POST variable. Thank you all for the help

Comment: you can also use array_values() to remove  keys from array

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can avoid array_push alltogether and just go $some_array[]=$some_value. I may be wrong but I remember reading somewhere that it was actually efficient (not that it matters anyway, since performance at these levels should not matter that much - unless your code spends too much time on it, of course).

Answer (score 2):

I have run this code and able to get all posted values

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action ="" method="POST" >
    <?php 
    //supose your values are 
    $content_ids = array('10','20');
    $x = 1;
    $content[$x]['TranslationID'] =20;
    // your code
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\" name=\"e\">";
    foreach($content_ids as $ids)
    {
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$ids."\" name=\"ids[]\">";
    }
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$content[$x]['TranslationID']."\" name=\"translationID\">";

    ?>
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Here the output

```
Array ( [e] => 1 [ids] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 20 ) [translationID] => 20 )
```

Comment: your code does work as intended, but mine still does not. My array "$content_ids" is being created from results from a database query. I am just looking at that to see if I have done that wrong. Although the array is populated with the correct results

Comment: can you please show output of your $content_ids with <?php print_r($content_ids); ?>

Comment: check value is empty or not before assign in array variable  if(trim($content[$i]['ContentID']) !='' ){ $content_ids[] = array_push($content_ids, $content[$i]['ContentID']); }