# Craft POST value so it seems like an array

Tags: php

Is it possible to manipulate `POST` value of `HTTP request` so

> var_dump($_POST['value']);

would like like an array? I am trying to understand posibility to use a bug explained in [ldap binding library](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76469)

if my ldap bind looks like in example

> $bind = ldap_bind( $ldap, "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" , $_POST['value']
>   );

what should `POST value` looks like in order to be bugged?

Comment: Yes it's possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, pass array through POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071587/php-pass-array-through-post)

Comment: To avoid the bug, I'd say use the [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a list of parameters as:

```
variable[]=value1&variable[]=value2
```

E.g. Executing this in Laravel:

```
dd(request()->variable);
```

By hitting:

```
your_url?variable[]=1&variable[]=2
```

Will print:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the third parameter to the ldap_bind function is the ldap password. So the value of $_POST['value'] should be a string. See the description of the ldap_bind function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php.

Comment: I'm fairly certain OP knows this already. It appears that `$_POST['value']` is being interpreted as an array and they'd like to know how that's happening

Comment: If the value field is being submitted by a form, then its possible to change the name of the field from value to for example value['test']. It will cause the value field to be submitted as an array. So $_POST['value'] will be array("test" => "some value"). The field name can be changed by manipulating the html DOM using the browsers developer console.