# Problem in getting multiple text input value

Tags: php, html

Below is my html code

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" required></td>
<td><input type="text" name="hsn[]" id="hsn_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" required></td>
<td><input type="text" name="hsn[]" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" required></td>
</tr>
```

Below is the code from which i am trying to get value

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST['item_name']);
```

But I am able to get single textbox value , not showing the both textbox value. Please help me where I am wrong
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you sent it with ajax or form?

Comment: check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071587/php-pass-array-through-post/29208714

Comment: form action method @SimoneRossaini

Comment: The form is not allowed into table take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table), use ajax for sent data.

Comment: form tag is outside the table and it is allowed @SimoneRossaini

Comment: Only in HTML5..

Comment: post all code html and php please.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini wrapping a form _around_ a table has not been a problem in HTML 4.01 either.

Comment: With the code you have shown, the problem is not reproducible (assuming you have `<form><table>…</table></form>` wrapped around this.)

Comment: I know this may sound obvious but we can't see it so please could you confirm the form's "method" is set to "post". The default method for sending the form data is "get" so if you have not set it to "post" that might be why.