# how to count not empty variables to get sum of non empty

Tags: php, forms, count

i have form giving sixth fields i want to count only the non empty

```
$first = $_POST['first'];

$second = $_POST['second'];
$third = $_POST['third'];
$fourth = $_POST['fourth'];
$fifth = $_POST['fifth'];
$sixth = $_POST['sixth'];
```

what i have tried to do is

```
$count = 0;

if(!empty($first)){ $count = 1;}
else if(!empty($second)) { $count = $count + 1;}
else if(!empty($third)) { $count = $count + 1;}
else if(!empty($fourth)) { $count =$count +  1;}
else if(!empty($fifth)) { $count =$count +  1;}
else if(!empty($sixth)) { $count =$count +  1;}
```

but its not working

Comment: Remove all `else` and your own code should work (It's so simple that I comment instead of answer).

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and the real problem is why you don't pass an `array` from your `HTML` form? that way your work gets a lot easier see for more [pass-array-through-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29208714/8740349)

Comment: $count = 0;

if(!empty($first))       { $count++;}
if(!empty($second)) { $count++;}
if(!empty($third))     { $count++;}
if(!empty($fourth))   { $count++;}
if(!empty($fifth))      { $count++;}
if(!empty($sixth))    { $count++;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use also array and loop it for better readability

```
$datas = [
  'first',
  'second',
  'third',
  'fourth',
  'fifth',
  'sixth'
];

$sum = 0;
foreach($datas as $data)
  if(!empty($_POST[$data])) $sum++;

echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use your code delete `else` and check each var like :

```
    $count = 0;
    if(!empty($first)){ $count = 1;}
    if(!empty($second)) { $count = $count + 1;}
    if(!empty($third)) { $count = $count + 1;}
    if(!empty($fourth)) { $count =$count +  1;}
    if(!empty($fifth)) { $count =$count +  1;}
    if(!empty($sixth)) { $count =$count +  1;}
```

Why don't check and sum directly in var :

```
$count = 0;
$first = !empty($_POST['first']) ? $_POST['first'] : $count += 1;
$second = !empty($_POST['second']) ? $_POST['second'] : $count += 1;
$third = !empty($_POST['third']) ? $_POST['third'] : $count += 1;
$fourth = !empty($_POST['fourth']) ? $_POST['fourth'] : $count += 1;
$fifth = !empty($_POST['fifth']) ? $_POST['fifth'] : $count += 1;
$sixth = !empty($_POST['sixth']) ? $_POST['sixth'] : $count += 1;
echo $count; // 6 (if all empty)
```

I use `shortcode` for see if `var` is `empty` then use `POST` or `$count + 1`.